# Creating a simple "shopping cart" program

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm trying to create a shopping cart program using the ArrayList class. My problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to exit out of the while loop once the user is done shopping. Items are entered as prices. Below is my code thus far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
**
* 
*/
public static void shoppingCart()
{
    Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner itemReader = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Would you like to input items? (y/n)");
    String input = inputReader.next();
    ArrayList<Double> items = new ArrayList<Double>();
    while (!input.equals("y") && !input.equals("n"))
    {
        System.out.print("Sorry, we need a (y/n): ");
        input = inputReader.next();
    }

    while (input.equals("y"))
    {
        while (!items.equals("-1"))
        {
            System.out.print("Please enter an item price, or -1 to exit: $");
            items.add(itemReader.nextDouble());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to get additional input from the user:

```
while (input.equals("y"))
{
    while (!items.equals("-1"))
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter an item price, or -1 to exit: $");
        items.add(itemReader.nextDouble());
    }

    // get the user's input here and set the input variable with it.

}
```

I would use just one Scanner tied to the System.in. I see no reason to use two.

Comment: `items.equals("-1")` - what's that supposed to mean? ;)

Comment: While this works, when the user enters "-1" to exit, why would you ask them for more input? Surely they just want to exit now.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you have way more loops than you really need. try something like this.
when you run a program like this where the user has to input a value to exit the program, that is what your while loop should be based off of, that way it will stay in the loop until the close command is offered.

```
while(!input.equals("-1")){
    //do your stuff here..
    if(!input.equals("y") || !input.equals("n")){
        //Try again...
        //input check
    }else{
        //do your stuff here...
        //input check
    }
}
if(input.equals("-1"){
    //Exit...
}
```

Comment: Tell me how it's possible for that while loop to finish and have `input.equals("-1")` be false.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand why you think it has to be false?
It's not false, it's just an input command in this context. The loop runs WHILE the command is NOT "-1". When the input command IS "-1" it will break out of the loop and exit the program.

Comment: Sorry I said that totally wrong, it is true or false. 
The while loop condition says if(NOT -1) so if(input != -1) it will return true and keep going. 
if(input == -1) then if(NOT -1) returns false and exits.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (input.equals("y"))
{
    while (!items.get(items.size()-1).equals("-1"))
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter an item price, or -1 to exit: $");
        items.add(itemReader.nextDouble());
    }
}
```

to

```
if (input.equals("y"))
{
    while (!items.equals("-1"))
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter an item price, or -1 to exit: $");
        items.add(itemReader.nextDouble());
    }
}
```

Should do it.

You have the "y" check only to check if you should loop and accept inputs. But when you finish entering inputs you don't want to loop and start that over again. An if statement is all you need with the loop inside it.

Comment: Thank you. After making the suggested changes, I am still unable to exit the while loop when I enter -1.

Comment: @user2930063 ah, that's because you were doing items.equals, but you need to get the last item first to check. See my new code. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems in this piece of code:

```
while (input.equals("y")) //input never changes in the loop so the loop will never end
    {
        while (!items.equals("-1")) //you're comparing ArrayList to a string. You need to 
        //compare list item (such as items.get(items.length()-1) to double (i.e. price)
        {
            System.out.print("Please enter an item price, or -1 to exit: $");
            items.add(itemReader.nextDouble());// there is no way to check what user 
            //entered because you add it to collection right away
        }
    }
```

What you really want is something like this:

```
if (input.eqals("y")) {
  while (true) {
    System.out.print("Please enter an item price, or -1 to exit: $");
    double price = itemReader.nextDouble();
    if (price < 0) {
     break;
    }
    items.add(price);
  }
}
```

Comment: I would rather `while (price < 0)`, and change the if statement to `if(price >= 0)items.add(price)`. I like infinite loops with breaks, but when you can avoid them easily, it's best